# How to perform semantic search on Hebrew documents using AWS OpenSearch?

Tags: opensearch, semantic-search

I am working on a project where I need to perform semantic search on **Hebrew** documents using AWS OpenSearch. I am wondering if it is **possible** to perform semantic search on Hebrew documents using OpenSearch? Does OpenSearch support tokenization or a way to search for similar words to the query and not exact words?

I have already looked through the OpenSearch documentation, but I could not find any information regarding the support for semantic search on non-English languages, particularly Hebrew. I have also tried searching for similar questions on StackOverflow, but most of them are focused on English language.

If anyone has any experience or knowledge on this topic, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or resources that could help me achieve semantic search on Hebrew documents using AWS OpenSearch. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: A quick search for "hebrew opensearch" yields [this](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-tp7uhxwardvmm) and [this](https://ey.fo/en/hebrew-search-for-elasticsearch-solr). Does it help?

Comment: I asked about cloud AWS Opensearch services. But I'll try to checkout if ey.fo can be used with them.
I thought maybe their is any special syntax that is not found in the documentation to use some hebrew tokenizer or similar approach.